# Find HitTestable ancestor widget in Flutter (TestCase)

Tags: flutter, testcase, finder

I am trying to find test navigation on tap of widget in flutter.

So far, I am able to find the Inkwell through key but that is not HitTestable so I am not able to tap on it through WidgetTester.

Now, I am looking to find out first HitTestable ancestor widget in the tree.

Here is how I am trying to find it.

```
final Finder inkwell = find.ancestor(
          of: find.text(
            'MyInkWellObject',
          ),
          matching: find.byType(InkWell).hitTestable(),
        );
expect(inkwell, findsOneWidget);
```

This works fine if I remove **hitTestable()**.

Any help will be appreciated.